# Are item level permissions copied during content deployment?

Tags: 2007, publishing-site, permissions

My internal site using AD authentication but has the role provider added to the web.config to allow the people picker resolve the relevant groups. I can then manage a documents item level permission and add or remove specific roles.

My external site uses FBA authentication with the same role provider details added in the web.config.

So by my reckoning I should be able to manage a documents item level permissions in the internal site – break inheritance, add or remove specific roles. Then I can perform a content deployment (full or incremental) and see these newly configured permission for that document copied across to the external site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify your deployment paths and such, there is an option to include permissions.

Comment: Doh! I look at it every day and don’t see it.